# Issue while configuring XPM

Tags: experience-manager

Getting following error when trying to open dropdown for "Alternative BluePrint Publication" in Setting slide out

```
/WebUI/Models/SiteEdit/Services/Services.svc/GetSiteEditItemConfiguration failed to execute. STATUS (404): Not Found
```

Answer (score 2):

First try to clear your browser cache and see if that fixes the problem.

If not, you should try doing a repair of the SDL Web installation.

A 404 error usually means that there is no resource at that URL; occasionally it means that the security settings prevent you from seeing the resource that is actually there. Neither of those situations happen out-of-the-box so something clearly broke your XPM installation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and fixed it.
Tridion\web\WebUI\Models\SiteEdit\Web.config had below line commented. Uncommented it restarted tridion services and issue got resolved.